# Is it possible to write one template function that accepts both rvalue and lvalue

Tags: c++, templates

I want to add the arithmetic overload for `std::vector` (probably not a very good idea but I want to use this as an example).  I can implement it as the following

```
template <typename T, typename T2> auto& operator+=(std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T2>& b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());

    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), std::plus<>());
    return a;
}

template <typename T, typename T2> auto operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, 
const std::vector<T2>& b)
{
    auto a0 = a;
    return a0 += b;
}

template <typename T, typename T2> auto operator+(std::vector<T>&& a, 
const std::vector<T2>& b)
{
    auto a0 = a;
    return a0 += b;
}
```

I need to write two function for `operator+` in order to exploit the rvalue sementic in C++11.  Is it possible to remove the duplicated code for `operator+`?

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to overload operators for types that aren't yours. It's confusing and might conflict with other code doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW, in your rvalue overload you should move(a), otherwise you're just copying it

Comment: OT suggestion: if you want arithmetic overload over `std::vector`, give a look at [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I shouldn't forget that!

Comment: @max66  I actually never know the existence of this container.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use *perfect-forwarding* and possibly constrain via SFINAE, something like

```
template<typename T>
struct is_vector_addable: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_vector_addable<std::vector<T>>: std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename T2,typename E=
std::enable_if_t< is_vector_addable<std::decay_t<T>>::value >>
auto operator+( T&& a,  const std::vector<T2>& b)
{
    auto a0 = std::forward<T>(a);
    return a0 += b;
}
```

as suggested by *Sebastian Redl*, you may also further constrain to std::vector's having addable elements ( in the sense of std::transform with std::plus semantics, this may or may not be what you really want ), in C++17:

```
template<typename T,typename T2,typename = void>
struct is_vector_addable: std::false_type {};

template<typename T,typename T2>
struct is_vector_addable<std::vector<T>,T2,std::void_t<
  decltype( std::declval<T>() = std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T2>() )
  >>: std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename T2,typename E=std::enable_if_t< is_vector_addable<std::decay_t<T>,T2>::value >>
auto operator+( T&& a,  const std::vector<T2>& b)
```

Comment: You could make it even more sophisticated by testing whether `T` is addable within `is_vector_addable`.

Comment: I found that I needed to use `std::move` anyway in the overloaded function so this might not be a good question.  But this answer is what I want previously.  Now I am going to use `std:valarray`.

Answer (score 4):

Whereas perfect forwarding is a solution in general case, an alternative is to pass by value:

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
auto operator+(std::vector<T> lhs, const std::vector<T2>& rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```